# Odoo 10 server boostrap error

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to run my Odoo 10 server through Eclipse but all I am is getting some error that I am not been able to understand. I think that my addons folder path is wrong. When Eclipse run the server file, it shows the wrong addon path . But I have set other addons path through the /debian/odoo.conf file.

```
1) Is there any other file where Odoo sets the path for addons folder?
2) Secondly I am getting 'bootstrap' File Error
```

.[image]

Hopes for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you need to install bootstrap in your system
please visit : https://getbootstrap.com/